# Subversion colored output for ZSH

Tags: svn, zsh

Does ZSH have any ready scripts to color the output of svn command (st, diff, so on)?

I found this little helper script for bash:

https://github.com/jmlacroix/svn-color/blob/master/svn-color.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell really has nothing to do with it. The [colorsvn](http://colorsvn.tigris.org/) tool will work with any shell. It's just a filter that intercepts output from the original program, run as a subprocess, and your terminal.  What language it's written in really doesn't matter much.